# King of the Cards

Tags: king-of-the-hill, card-games

## King of the Cards

*Code available [here](https://gist.github.com/GingerIndustries/7c2ea84cb7cb38307382892b1529a777)!*

In this King of the Hill challenge, you must write a bot that can play [Crazy Eights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Eights). This is a card game often played by children, in which the objective is to empty your hand.

### How to Play

The game of Crazy Eights is deceptively simple. At the beginning of the game, each player gets dealt a hand of cards (in this case eight), with the remaining cards placed in the middle of the table as the draw pile. The top card is then placed face up and serves as the beginning of the discard pile. Then, each player can discard one card per turn if that card has a matching suit or rank with the top card on the discard pile. They may also play an 8, which allows them to change the effective suit of the 8 and therefore the suit the next player must follow. The played card then becomes the top card. If the player does not have any matching cards, they must draw from the draw pile until they get a matching card and play that. If they exhaust the draw pile, play passes to the next player. Players may draw at any time, even if they have playable cards (which does not count as a turn).

For example, if 6♣ is played, the next player:

- Can play a 6 of any suit
- Can play any club
- Can play an 8 (and then must declare a suit)
- Can draw and continue their turn.

If the draw pile runs out, then the discard pile (except for the top card) is shuffled and becomes the new draw pile.

The game ends once a player runs out of cards, in which case they are declared the winner. (This differs from normal Crazy Eights, and is included to make this game a bit simpler.)

## Bots

Bots must be written in Python. Bots will have access to the `kotc` module, which supplies these classes:

- `KOTCBot`, which bots must extend
- `Card`, which represents a card
- `Suit` and `Rank`, enums representing the suit and value of a card

Bots must implement a `play` method, which takes as input a `Card` representing the top card on the discard pile. This method must return a `Card` within that bot's `hand`. If the returned `Card` is not in the bot's `hand` that bot is disqualified. (I will leave a comment on it with information about the state of the game when it happened.) However, if the `Card` is an `Eight` then only the `rank` will be checked against the bot's `hand`. If the bot has no playable cards in its hand, the `play` method will ***NOT*** be called and the controller will automatically draw cards on behalf of the bot and add them to its `hand`. **The bot should NEVER modify its `hand`!** This will be done by the controller. The `play` method may also return `None` or `False`, which will cause its turn to be skipped.

Bots will compete against each other in matches of two, in an elimination-style tournament bracket. The winner will advance onwards, and the loser will be <s>executed</s> eliminated.

## API

### `KOTCBot`

This class is the actual bot.

Methods and properties: (Do NOT override any of these in your bot)

- `draw`: When called, this function draws a card from the pile and adds it to the bot's hand. It also returns the card drawn.
- `hand`: This property is a list of `Card`s representing the bot's hand.
- `arena`: This property is the `KOTCArena` instance the bot is playing in.

### `KOTCArena`

This class is accessible through the `arena` property of the `Bot`. It has three functions available to the bots:

- `handSizes`: Returns a list of the lengths of the hands of the other bots
- `discardSize`: Returns the size of the discard pile
- `drawSize`: Returns the size of the draw pile

### `Card`

The `Card` class represents a card, and takes a `Suit` and `Rank` when constructed.  This class must be returned by the bot's `play` method. Its suit and rank can be accessed through their respective properties.

- `all`: This classmethod takes no parameters and returns a 52-item list of all possible card combinations.

*Note: All enumeration members are UPPERCASE.*

### `Suit`

Members of this enum:

- `CLUBS`
- `DIAMONDS`
- `SPADES`
- `HEARTS`

### `Rank`

Members of this enum:

- `ACE`
- `KING`
- `QUEEN`
- `JACK`
- `TWO` through `TEN`

## Example Bot

This bot just plays any available card, without using eights.

```python
import kotc

class ExampleBot(kotc.KOTCBot):
  def play(self, discard):
    for card in self.hand:
      if card.suit == discard.suit or card.rank == discard.rank:
        return card
```

Comment: You could instead run bots in rounds of three or four at a time. I think a tournament bracket relies on a lot of luuck.

Comment: @emanresuA I intend to run each game multiple times to fix this.

Comment: "Players may draw at any time, even if they have playable cards (which does not count as a turn)." So for our bots, that means we can call `self.draw()` from within the `play` method if we like, correct? It might be worth mentioning that in the "Bots" section; I found it confusing at first.

Comment: How many players each game? How many cards are used? 52 or more?

Comment: "Players may draw at any time"; what will happen if we run out of cards, even discarded before? For example, I write `while True: self.draw()`?

Comment: Could you post the code for running a simulation of the KOTC? I would like to test things out on my own, as well as solve the ambiguities, such as the actual code of your enums. Finally, for convenience, could you add a function that returns a list of all 52 possible cards?

Comment: @RyanFu Of course. I'll tell you when I have.

Comment: @RyanFu Done.‍‌‍

Comment: @Ginger are we allowed to look at the discard pile?

Comment: @Ginger I took the liberty of clearning up your runner code and fixing some bugs. Feel free to use any of it: https://controlc.com/f1b46963.

Comment: Is the simulation going to use an actual 52 card deck with 52 unique cards in it or does it just give me a random card whenever I draw one?

Comment: @Ginger v2: https://controlc.com/c2833074

Answer (score 3):

## BasicBot

```python
import kotc
from random import shuffle
class BasicBot(kotc.KOTCBot):
  shuffle(self.hand)
  def play(self, discard):
    for card in self.hand:
      if (card.rank == kotc.Rank.EIGHT):
        playables = 0
        for card2 in self.hand:
          if card.suit == discard.suit or card.rank == discard.rank:
            playables+=1
        if playables<2:
          return card2

      if card.suit == discard.suit or card.rank == discard.rank:
        return card
    for card in self.hand:
        if card.suit == discard.suit or card.rank == discard.rank:
            return card
```

I think this will work. Pretty much ExampleBot, except it will play an eight if it has less than two other cards it can play. Currently doesn't prioritize playing a specific suit (that's next on my list of goals) but it still should be better than BasicBot.

Comment: How would I declare a suit? I don't know if that's working right now.

Comment: I edited it for you.

Comment: I don't think this works as is, because random.shuffle shuffles the list in place and returns None

Comment: You want `for card in shuffle(self.hand) or self.hand:` if you want to shuffle your hand in the `for` statement. Or simply call `shuffle(self.hand)` in the line before `for card in self.hand)`.

Comment: Have you tested ExampleBot vs BasicBot?

Comment: This bot tries to play invalid cards.

Comment: How would I fix that?